# How save image in Android Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, universal-image-loader, android-lazyadapter

In `Lazy-List` i use this code and my image store in a folder named `LazyList`

`ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView);`

But in `Universal-Image-Loader` i use this

```
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())    
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.test_id);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(URL.RECIPE_IMG_URL,img);
```

but each time it use internet to get image and didn't store my image in any folder i aslo add `.diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(new File("myFolder")))` to `config`
but nothing store in `myFolder`.Any ideas?

Comment: `new File("myFolder")` it's not a location that your app have access to. You probably want to use `context.getCacheDir()`.

Comment: is use `context.getCacheDir()` this first then change it to other things but nothing change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer . By default caching is disable i should add `DisplayImageOptions` to `ImageLoaderConfiguration`

And here is code

```
   DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .build();
```

Comment: Are you able to save images to your phone using UIL after this code change ?

Comment: Thats great . I added this code in ImageLoaderConfiguration  but am not getting it saved . Could you please brief me the steps ?Have you made any other changes ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to save the Image on `onLoadingComplete`

try this , on `onLoadingComplete` you have to save the `bitmap` to a variable `bitmap`

```
imageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imagePath, imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            String message = null;
            switch (failReason.getType()) {
            case IO_ERROR:
                message = "Input/Output error";
                break;
            case DECODING_ERROR:
                message = "Image can't be decoded";
                break;
            case NETWORK_DENIED:
                message = "Downloads are denied";
                break;
            case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                message = "Out Of Memory error";
                break;
            case UNKNOWN:
                message = "Unknown error";
                break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            showedImgae = loadedImage;

        }
    });
```

now onclick on save Button / if you want to save that `Bitmap`/`Image` to `SDCard`  use this

```
 public void downloadImage(){

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/DCIM/youfoldername");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "imagename-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        showedImgae.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Thanks Rajesh . But i have a big question , Lazy list save images in its default folder and Universal Image Loader is a fork of lazy list .It doesn't have any function or something else to do this automatically does it?

Comment: What if i need to save only current VISIBLE image in PageAdapter?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh Mikkilineni I followed this but the image saved cannot be opened. Do you know what could be causing that? thanks!

Comment: please check file type your saving